# How to apply 3 or 4 or variable number of filters on firebase database or is there any other service which can help us

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to filter my data with multiple fields like sex, price, single or double type, is subscribed or not and more filters which can be applied by a user. I have searched the whole stack but they tell to make a special key in a database which is useless in my case.

In my case number of filters is variable is their solution to the firebase problem

I have tried following stack answers:

[How to filter firebase data results by applying multiple Query in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034925/how-to-filter-firebase-data-results-by-applying-multiple-query-in-android)

[Firebase DatabaseReference filter by specified values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179097/firebase-databasereference-filter-by-specified-values)

[Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase?rq=1)

[How to query by multiple keys in Firebase Database list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419871/how-to-query-by-multiple-keys-in-firebase-database-list)

Comment: If you aren't able to follow the advice in the other questions, then what you're trying to do is not possible.  You simply can't filter on multiple fields in Realtime Database. You should probably use Cloud Firestore instead.

Comment: Agreed with Doug here: the answers to the questions you found give a good outline of your options. A synthetic property that combines the values might be possible, but honestly is also a bit limiting. If that doesn't work, Cloud Firestore might be a good option as long as you *can* get your use-case implemented within the limitations of the query model that database.

Comment: 1) I have tried it doing multiple query and I'm able to do it but all data id filtered on user and then filtered and if database is very big it will be very slow .  2)  On cloud firestore will the data will be queried according to user filter ?